# Installing Ubuntu MATE

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

So, before I install Ubuntu MATE, I have files on my microSD card from my other Pi (that broke) and I am wondering if I can boot another Pi (a school-owned one) to transfer the files. Can I boot the pi's card from another Pi, transfer the files off of, and erase the card to install Ubuntu MATE?

Also, where and how can I get the files to boot to Ubuntu MATE on the PI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its always best to have a couple of SD cards around - it can be easy to 'break' an OS with a wrong install while playing around (done it a few times before now). Personally, I find 16Gb cards the best price to size ratio for my use.

But to answer your questions:

1. Yes you can access the data on the Pi SD card - just use a (Micro) SD to USB adapter and use the file explorer to find the files you want to keep as it is a Linux computer.

- Windows machine can access the boot portion natively but needs something like [Diskinternals](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) to read the ext4 partition.
- Mac users often use the chargeable [extFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) (my preferred option) or free BUT read only [ext4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse)

2. Ubuntu images for the files are now available direct from them [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) with basic desktop install instructions for the Pi 4 [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#1-overview) **BUT** as you are after Mate, then head direct to the Mate support site [ubuntu-mate.org](https://ubuntu-mate.org) and download their ready configured images [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/ports/raspberry-pi/)

Edited: 3/11/20
Note that the Mate team recommends a **Pi 4 with 2GB** or the equivalent compute module - no mention is made of the Pi 400 at this date

Comment: So, is there like a zip where I have to extract and drag-and-drop on the empty microSD card and just slip it in the Pi?

Comment: Please follow the links for install instructions - I use Etcher to put the image on the cards https://www.balena.io/etcher/  Note that the Mate team recommends a Pi 4 with 2GB or the equivalent compute module - no mention is made of the new Pi 400

Comment: I might get the Pi 400, I can't beat a Pi 4 inside of a keyboard. Balena Etcher is nice, but it needs admin crap on macOS which I don't have. Can I boot Ubuntu MATE via noobs if I drop the files into its own folder?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I found a NOOBS image for Ubuntu MATE (15.10, need to upgrade to 20.04) and can drag and drop the files from that.